# href: link back to certain class on previous single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a single page website and for some showcase of work of the owner I redirect the user to a second html with detailed information, pictures etc. Now if the user clicks on the back link I can send him back to the main single page website but it should be a lot more user friendly if he was instant redirected to the section (= a class named work) where he left off.

So is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean any clearer? It's not obvious what you're asking. Seeing your code may help.

Comment: I think you mean anchors rather than class (anchors work with IDs)

Comment: Have a read on history and push state, great solution for SPAs http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: Some browsers already do this natively.  For example in chrome if I scroll to the bottom of this page, follow a link in the footer, and then hit the back button It takes me back to the footer of this page.  

I'd advise going against changing native behaviour as it can be counter-intuitive going against what the user is expecting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="index.html#work">Back</a>
```

But you need to use an ID, not a class...

```
<section id="work">...</section>
```